# Stop Facebook Pulling Video - OpenGraph Meta Data

Tags: facebook, video, youtube, metadata, facebook-opengraph

I've been creating a website that features videos, I have it updating the Facebook page automatically. However when it updates the Facebook page it's pulling the (Youtube or other) video into the page so people can watch it directly on Facebook.

Is there any way to stop this as I would like to direct traffic to the website instead.

I've tried the Meta Data such as `<og:image>` etc.. but that just replaces the image thumbnail but still have the play button on top of it.

If you need more information let me know.
Thank you

Comment: Do you have an og:video tag on your page? if so, remove it.